# Accessing nested data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble getting the correct data in my web app from Firebase.

The problem is that the data I want in a object named 'random number'. I want to be able to bring all my fields into variables so I can test, set up my page to display all the data, that sort of thing. But I am lost on how to query these keys in order to use them.

[image: database]

Right now I am just logging the data to the console to get a feel for the data structure. PS. I didn't organize the data, someone did it before me.

[image: code]

Where I have the two commented out variables with I had tried to even type in one of the key's to see if I could get the data but it does not work.

Comment: You need to be clearer. Which keys are random? And how do you want to query it? Did you want to query using a particular open ticket property?

Comment: Right now, below openTickets is a list of tickets with random keys for names. I am new to Firebase and I am more used to JSON data and just being able to get to the data I want super easily. I'm just proof of concept testing things as I go. I want to pick a ticket from the DB and console.log that tickets data. At this point with what I have I get console.log of everything in Inspectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are retrieving everything under the `inspectors`, you can access the data like this:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child('inspectors')
  .once('value', function (inspectorsSnapshot) {

    inspectorsSnapshot
      .child('obfuscated') // This key is obfuscated in your question.
      .child('openTickets')
      .forEach(function (openTicketSnapshot) {
        console.log(openTicketSnapshot.key); // The random key.
        var val = openTicketSnapshot.val();
        console.log(val.address);
        console.log(val.assignedInspector);
        // etc.
      });
  });
```

You can also refine the query itself to retrieve only the data you want:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child('inspectors')
  .child('obfuscated') // This key is obfuscated in your question.
  .child('openTickets')
  .once('value', function (openTicketsSnapshot) {

    openTicketsSnapshot.forEach(function (openTicketSnapshot) {
      console.log(openTicketSnapshot.key); // The random key.
      var val = openTicketSnapshot.val();
      console.log(val.address);
      console.log(val.assignedInspector);
      // etc.
    });
  });
```

And, if you only want the first few entries:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child('inspectors')
  .child('obfuscated') // This key is obfuscated in your question.
  .child('openTickets')
  .limitToFirst(10)
  .once( ... // etc.
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I didn't realize you can chain two child methods. I think I know what to do now. I will need to get the obviscated into a variable and the put that in there.